# React Native - Error - require.cache shows undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In React Native ,
I need to clear the `require.cache`, but `require.cache` shows `undefined`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise it is a bit hard to help you, as we have no idea what's going on either